# Allowing Users to create custom groups of Countries

Tags: drupal-6, grouping, countries

I'm working on a project for a customer, and one of the requirements is that Users should be allow to assign to each Product (in their case, a Node) a Country or a Region, where the Region is simply a group of Countries, not necessarily in the same area.

I've seen there are many different ways to manage a list of Countries, often suggesting to use Taxonomy for them, but I can't figure out how could I allow users to create these "Regions". To make things complicated, customer wants to have a simple interface, where only one field is present on the form. In this field, Users must be able to choose either a Country or a Region.

Perhaps I could implement everything using Nodes, i.e.:
- Country Nodes
- Region Nodes, with a multiple-valued Node Reference to Country Nodes

But I wonder if that would not be too heavy...

I hope the issue is clear, if not feel free to ask and I'll try to explain it better. Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own tables and code to handle the whole thing, as I couldn't find any better solution. I used tables from IP2Country module as a source for Country Codes.